# DNS configuration in prestashop

Tags: dns

I have a folder with a prestashop installed hosted on OVH.

I have a domain on AWS.

I configured DNS to be able to use my domain with this hosting, but there is always a redirection when i go to my domain, to the path where my folder is located on hosting.

How can i do to keep domain url as root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regenerate Prestashop .htaccess by going in "**Seo & URL**" menu and saving from there.

Also make sure that you shop domain and base URI are correct in the bottom section of the same page.